# problems overriding 3rd party extension block class

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks, overrides, class

the extension in question has the following structure:

- app

  - code

    - local

      - MST

        - Menupro

          - Block

            - Base.php

Base.php has:

```
class MST_Menupro_Block_Base extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
```

my custom module

- app

  - code

    - local

      - Myname

        - BlockOverride

          - Block

            - Base.php

my Base.php has:

```
class Myname_BlockOverride_Block_Base extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
```

In my module activation file Myname_BlockOverride.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
           <Myname_BlockOverride>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
                    <active>true</active>
                    <depends>
                        <MST_Menupro/>
                    </depends>
           </Myname_BlockOverride>
       </modules>
    </config>
```

module is verified as enabled and working because I am overriding some mage core classes also.

in:

- app

  - code

    - local

      - Myname

        - BlockOverride

          - etc

            - config.xml

i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Myname_BlockOverride>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Myname_BlockOverride>
        </modules>

        <global>
            <blocks>
                <myname_blockoverride>
                    <class>Myname_BlockOverride_Block</class>
                </myname_blockoverride>
                <menupro>
                    <rewrite>
                        <base>Myname_BlockOverride_Block_Base</base>
                    </rewrite>
                </menupro>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

This question has been asked multiple times, like here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145976/how-to-rewrite-extend-a-magento-class-in-an-existing-third-party-extension
and 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-overriding-in-magento-blocks--cms-23325
and
[Rewrite a local Extension Module doesn't work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/rewrite-a-local-extension-module-doesnt-work)

which i've dutifully followed through but seem to up against a brick wall.
my overriding class file is never loaded (error_log at top of file does not fire).

any help greatly appreciated.

edit: i checked through the 3rd party extension for their block definition in config.xml and see

```
<blocks>
    <menupro>
        <class>MST_Menupro_Block</class>
    </menupro>
</blocks>
```

not sure if i'm missing a clue there somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a direct answer to this question which i never solved satisfactorily, I did work around this by moving the 3rd party extension to community pool and override it via file inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes I can find.

1. You placed your module files in wrong place
2. You rewrote the custom module's block class in wrong way.

### Place files in correct location

**Activation File** : `app/etc/modules/Myname_BlockOverride.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Myname_BlockOverride>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
                <active>true</active>
                <depends>
                    <MST_Menupro/>
                </depends>
       </Myname_BlockOverride>
   </modules>
</config>
```

**config file** : `app/code/local/Myname/BlockOverride/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myname_BlockOverride>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myname_BlockOverride>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <myname_blockoverride>
                <class>Myname_BlockOverride_Block</class>
            </myname_blockoverride>
            <menupro>
                <rewrite>
                    <base>Myname_BlockOverride_Block_Base</base>
                </rewrite>
            </menupro>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Rewrite Class** : `app/code/local/Myname/BlockOverride/Block/Base.php`

```
<?php
class Myname_BlockOverride_Block_Base extends MST_Menupro_Block_Base
{

}
```

and that's it. Last and but not least, you **need to clear your caches**. Ready, Set, Goooooooo....

Comment: Hi Rajeev, thank you for the reply, but unfortunately I made a typo when writing my question. Both my activation and config file have been in the correct path from the beginning (question updated accordingly). 
All caches are currently disabled (but yes I flushed them all just to make sure).

Comment: your activation file name is wrong. check "activation file" part in my answer

Comment: damn, should proofread my question better :( but I assure you my activation file is correct. the module is registered to magento and activated, I am using it to perform other successful overrides. Question updated accordingly. Thank you again for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your extension `BlockOverride` `block.php` should be

`class Myname_BlockOverride_Block_Base extends MST_Menupro_Block_Base {`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i'm afraid that doesn't work in this case. Or it's not the entire problem. The error_log (at the top of the custom Base.php file) is never called, so that file is not parsed.

Comment: edit: Sorry i just realized you specified block.php (assuming Block.php, maybe that doesn't matter). I created Block.php and added the class definition, that file also is never executed.